# How can I solve the "Source not found" of a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I download the tutorial from the link[2](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Text-To-Speech-Tutorial). When I try to read the function of RobotiserEffect, I find that it warns me about the "Source not found" problem. After I add the jar file path, I still can't read the detail of the function. By the way, as the Bug pic[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPjZc.png) shown, I can see the function under the bug description. How can I correct this problem?

Bug picture:
[image: Bug pic]

[Tutorial Link](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Text-To-Speech-Tutorial)

Comment: `marytts-builder-5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar` contains `.class` files (bytecode) only, not the source code (`.java` files). Try to download and attach the source from here (_Source code (zip)_): https://github.com/marytts/marytts/releases/tag/v5.2

Comment: Thx! It works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`marytts-builder-5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar` contains** `.class` files (bytecode) only, **not the source code** (`.java` files).

Try to download and attach the source from the [MaryTTS project](http://github.com/marytts/marytts/): "***[Source code (zip)](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/archive/v5.2.zip)***"